# Android : SharedPreferences and MVC pattern

Tags: android, model-view-controller, sharedpreferences

I'm developping my app using the MVC pattern. To store/access data, my controllers use a class named "DataStorage", and for now this class allows to store/access simple parameters about my app (username, data storage path, ...). In other words, I want to call a few methods like "getParameter(String key)" or "setParameter(String key, String value)".
I think SharedPreferences would be the most convenient way to store these parameters, so my get/setParameters use this class.

In all the examples I have seen, SharedPreferences is called from an Activity and there is no problem to call methods such as "getSharedPreferences" or "getApplicationContext"/"getContext". Because my DataStorage class is not an activity, for now I ask my first activity to give its context when creating a new DataStorage instance, and it works well to store my parameters. My problem : I want to be able to remove parameters from another activity using clear + commit methods. But it doesn't work (parameters are still there), and I think the reason is I give the 2nd activity context when creating another instance of DataStorage. The problem might be something else though, I've been practicing Android for only 2 days now...

To summarize how my app works :

- Activity 1 creates a DataStorage class and provides its context to the DataStorage constructor. The DataStorage might store a parameter into a SharedPreferences file (or not...)
- When I run my app again, if a particular parameter is set in the SharedPreferences file, then I start Activity 2 instead of Activity 1. Using the menu on Activity 2, I want to be able to clear the SharedPreferences file (in order to get Activity 1 again when I restart the app), so I create another DataStorage instance (and I provide Activity 2 context) and I call the method to clear all parameters.

As I said, first part works well (I can store parameters), but clear & commit do nothing to my SharedPreferences file.
I don't want to put a piece of code for this directly in my activities.

Can you help me with this ? What am I doing wrong in the way I use SharedPreferences ?

Thank you for your help !

Edit :

```
public class DataStorage {

    private Context context;
    private String settingsFilename;
    private SharedPreferences settings;

    public DataStorage(Context activityContext, String filename) {
        context = activityContext;
        settingsFilename = filename;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(settingsFilename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void newSharedPreference(String key, String value) {
        settings.edit().putString(key, value).apply();
        settings.edit().commit();
    }

    public String getSharedPreference(String key) {
        return settings.getString(key, null);
    }

    public void clearPreferences() {
        settings.edit().clear();
        settings.edit().commit();
        Toast.makeText(context,settings.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

In my first activity (the code is part of onCreate method) :

```
DataStorage storage = new DataStorage(this, getResources().getString(R.string.sharedPreferencesFile));
        username = storage.getSharedPreference("username");
        Toast.makeText(this, username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (username != null) {
            Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, ActivityMainMenu.class);
            startActivity(nextActivity);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
        }
```

In my 2nd activity :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch(id) {
            case R.id.action_clearSharedPref :
                storage.clearPreferences();
                break;
            case R.id.action_leave :
                System.exit(RESULT_OK);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

(Storage is constructed exactly as I did in my first Activity)

I tried to replace "this" by getApplicationContext() in DataStorage constructor, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide full code of `DataStorage` and its usage at activities.

Comment: Done. Tell me if you need more information

Comment: Couldn't your `DataStorage` class extend `Activity` as well?

Comment: @Chugrothas How storage is declared at 2nd activity?

Comment: @miav : technically I guess I could, but is that a correct way to solve the problem ? I thought Activity were used to interact with the user, and if I'm right I would prefer to avoid that solution... As I said, I don't really know Android so maybe I just didn't get all the concepts.

Comment: @gio : Storage is declared exactly as I did in the 1st activity :
DataStorage storage = new DataStorage(this, getResources().getString(R.string.sharedPreferencesFile));
I declare storage in "onCreate" method of the 2nd activity.

Comment: @Chugrothas wouldn't be so bad in my opinion. An Activity exists as a UI object only if you declare it in your manifest file. Anyway glad you solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) Class Overview

> Interface used for modifying values in a SharedPreferences object. All changes you make in an editor are batched, and not copied back to the original `SharedPreferences` until you call `commit()` or `apply()`.

You need to update to change methods at your `DataStorage`

```
public void newSharedPreference(String key, String value) {
        settings.edit().putString(key, value).apply();
}
```

and

```
public void clearPreferences() {
    settings.edit().clear().apply();
    Toast.makeText(context,settings.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Reason of issue is next

```
    settings.edit().clear(); // clear is ok, but it won't be saved because 
    settings.edit().commit(); // create new editor and commit nothing
```

Comment: It works. Thank you, I didn't understand I wasn't really working on the same editors.

Comment: You create editor clear it but **did not** apply changes on it.